# Insert newly added Item at the top of an EnhancedGrid in Dojo

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have an `EnhancedGrid` which is bound to a dynamic Store. I am using lazy loading, so as I scroll down, more data will be fetched and bound.

I also have an "add new Item" functionality. This will open a pop-up where the user creates the new Item in a form, and on Save the item is added to the store. with `dojo.data.ObjectStore.newItem()` and `dojo.data.ObjectStore.save()`.

My problem, after using those two functions, the item is automatically appended to the grid at the **bottom**, which is kinda of a nuisance. The user will have to scroll down to find it, which would trigger the lazy loading.

After following the code around, I found out that `newItem()` calls the `dojox.grid.DataGrid._addItem(item, index, noUpdate)` function.

I managed to overwrite it so when I am adding a new item, the _addItem function will be called with index 0. But that does not work since it was just replacing the first row with the new one instead of prepending it.

Is there any other way to look at this? is it possible to actually do it?